# Equal Distribution of random treatment in previously made groups in R

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R and I am struggling to randomize a treatment when ID and Sex have already been assigned. In this code, the shadow treatment is not equally distributed in each female and male groups (5 females receives Shadow, whereas 3 receives the No Shadow. Same for the males)

```
library(randomizr)

id <- as.factor(c(1:16)) #Fish ID
sex <- as.factor (c("Female", "Female", "Male", "Male",
                    "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male",
                    "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male",
                    "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male"))

set.seed(123)

treatments <- complete_ra(N = 16, #Nbr of individuals 
                          num_arms = 2, #Nbr of treatments
                          condition = c("No Shadow", "Shadow"))#treatment names


data_sheet <- data.frame(id, sex, treatments)

print (data_sheet)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can use stratified random sampling. Try this: `sex <- rep(c("F", "M"), times = c(8, 8)); treatments <- strata_rs(strata = sex); treatments <- factor(treatments, labels=c("No Shadow", "Shadow"))`.